# Convert 16 bits to 4 char ( in Hexadecimal)

Tags: c++, converters, visual-studio-express

I want to convert 16 bit to 4 characters which are in Hexadecimal character.
For example, a 16 bit, 1101 1010 1101 0001 in hexadecimal is DAD1 and in decimal is 56017. Now I want to convert this 16 bit into DAD1 as characters so that I can use the character to write into a text file.

My coding part, my variable "CRC" is my result from CRC checksum. Now I want to convert 16 bit "CRC" into 4 characters which are DAD1 (capital letters).

```
cout << hex << CRC<<endl;
char lo = CRC & 0xFF;
char hi = CRC >> 8;
cout << hi << endl;
cout << lo;
```

*******Result********

dad1

┌

₸

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int i = 56017;
    std::cout <<hex <<i << std::endl;
    std::bitset<16> bin = i;
    std::string str = bin.to_string();
    std::bitset<8> hi(str.substr(0, 8));
    std::bitset<8> lo(str.substr(8, 8));
    std::cout << bin << std::endl;
    std::cout << hi << " " << hi.to_ullong() << std::endl;
    std::cout << lo << " " << lo.to_ullong() << std::endl;
}
```

OR  you can also do

```
std::cout <<hex << (CRC & 0xFF)<< std::endl;
std::cout << hex << (CRC >> 8) << std::endl;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int i = 56017;
    std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits> b(i); 
    std::cout<< std::hex << b.to_ullong();    
}
```